# Getting image from dicom .DCM file in node.js

Tags: node.js, image, dicom

I would like to generate a thumbnail image from a .dcm file (Dicom) in node.js.

So far I've found a node modules called [`dicom-parser`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPghm.png) that extracts the metadata from a dcm file.

My test case :

```
var dicom = require('dicom-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

var dicomFileAsBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./FullPano.dcm');

var dataSet = dicom.parseDicom(dicomFileAsBuffer);

var pixelData = new Uint8Array(dataSet.byteArray.buffer, 
                                dataSet.elements.x00880200.items[0].dataSet.elements.x7fe00010.dataOffset, 
                                dataSet.elements.x00880200.items[0].dataSet.elements.x7fe00010.length);

fs.writeFileSync('test5.jpg', pixelData); // <----- not working :'(
```

To help you help me debug, here is the `dataSet.elements.x00880200` object :

[image: dataSet.elements.x00880200]

But the pixelData stored in the tag x00880200 -> x7fe00010 is not in a standard format, either jpeg, jpg, png... The idea here is to get the thumbnail of a dcm image directly from a file, on the fly, server-side in nodejs.

From the [dicom doc](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part03.html#sect_C.7.6.1.1.6) (see below), the tag 0088,0200 holds the data for the icon, aka thumbnail.

> Icon Image Sequence
>
> (0088,0200)
>
> 3
>
> This icon image is representative of the Image.
>
> Only a single Item is permitted in this Sequence.

I've come around the `cornerstone` libs : [`cornerstone-js`](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone/issues/246) and [`wado-image-loader`](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone/issues/246). But neither are working in a node.js environment (made an [issue about that](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone/issues/246)). These libs can generate the "main" image of a dcm, but only once the dcm file is loaded on the cliend-side, in js. My requirement is to do that in nodejs, for the icon/thumbnail.

Comment: _"the generated image is not exploitable"_ Can you clarify this? What did you use to check the image? Also, can you provide more information about that DICOM object? (Some fields are really important, such as the transfer syntax.) Without it, we cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Updated the whole answer for more clarity and to add more details on my journey to dicom. 
"What did you use to check the image?" -> the image is not visible through the OS standard viewer + I checked in an hex editor and none of the tests images contains the jpg or png HEX header.
Thus I don't think knowing all the fields of the dcm would help you in helping me. Dcm tags are standards and documented.

Comment: @MarcelFalliere did you manage to retrieve the images?

Comment: @HRK44 not with dicom-parser. We now use Cornerstone to display .dcm in a canvas on the web.

Comment: @MarcelFalliere I managed to get it working, since the dicom parser returns RAW pixel data, I just had to encode to JPEG or PNG or w/e format you want before creating the file.

Comment: @HRK44 congrats! Actually what you did was my original question. Out of curiosity, how exactly do you save the raw pixel data to JPEG ?

Comment: @MarcelFalliere you just need to use an encoder (for example if you want JPEG you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js), then once you have the encoded data, you do what you want with it - create new file, base64 it, etc...

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to save the image icon as a JPG, that may be your issue:

> Only monochrome and palette color images shall be used. Samples per Pixel (0028,0002) shall have a Value of 1, Photometric Interpretation (0028,0004) shall have a Value of either MONOCHROME 1, MONOCHROME 2 or PALETTE COLOR, Planar Configuration (0028,0006) shall not be present.<sup>[source](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part03.html#sect_C.7.6.1.1.6)</sup>

I'm not familiar with node.js, but the data in the Icon Image Sequence may not be appropriate for that call.

Note also that you are getting an optional, small, thumbnail of the image, not the actual image data, which can be found in the Pixel Data attribute (7FE0,0010).

Comment: I am specifically looking for the thumbnail of the image. So now the question is : from the pixelData stored in the dcm file, how to generate an image file encoded in JPEG or PNG ? In either a file (.jpg, .png, ...) or a data:uri ?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but, if you are still looking for an answer, you can use [dcmjs-imaging](https://github.com/PantelisGeorgiadis/dcmjs-imaging) (full disclosure, I am the author). The library implements a DICOM image and overlay rendering pipeline, for Node.js and browser.
The library supports uncompressed data but also, optionally, decodes all major transfer syntaxes using a native WebAssembly module.
Given that you have already fetched the the DICOM bytes in an `ArrayBuffer`, you can use the following Node.js example to render the image in an RGBA pixel `ArrayBuffer`.

```js
// Import objects
const dcmjsImaging = require('dcmjs-imaging');
const { DicomImage, NativePixelDecoder } = dcmjsImaging;

// Optionally register native decoders WebAssembly.
// If native decoders are not registered, only 
// uncompressed syntaxes would be able to be rendered.
await NativePixelDecoder.initializeAsync();

// Create an ArrayBuffer with the contents of the DICOM P10 byte stream.
const image = new DicomImage(arrayBuffer);

// Render image.
const renderingResult = image.render();

// Rendered pixels in an RGBA ArrayBuffer.
const renderedPixels = renderingResult.pixels;
// Rendered width.
const width = renderingResult.width;
// Rendered height.
const height = renderingResult.height;
```